# Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have the following code that is causing me an error stating Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined

```
      <div class="extra">
        <p><%- blog.body.substring(0, 120) %> ... </p>
        <a href="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>">Read More</a>
      </div>
```

However the error is occuring on my index.js page only when new content is added to the page, not on the existing content. I am using express on the backend. The change that I have made was

```
router.post("/blogs", isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    // create blog
    req.body.blog.body = req.sanitize(req.body.blog.body);
    Blog.create(req.body.blog, function(err, newBlog){
        if(err){
            res.render("blogs/new");
        } else {
            //then, redirect to the index
            res.redirect("/blogs");
        }
    });
});
```

to this

```
// CREATE ROUTE
router.post("/blogs", isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    var title = req.body.title;
    var image = req.body.image;
    var description =  req.body.description;
    var author = {
        id: req.user._id,
        username: req.user.username
    }
    var blogPost = {title: title, image: image, description: description, author: author}
    req.body.blog.body = req.sanitize(req.body.blog.body);
    Blog.create(blogPost, function(err, newBlog){
        if(err){
            res.render("blogs/new");
        } else {
            //then, redirect to the index
            res.redirect("/blogs");
```

Comment: The template engine is EJS

Comment: your blog.body prop is emty/undefined nothing to work with. Make sure it got the string

Answer (score 0):

check this out you should pass data to render method to access it in template engine so you don't have any data in page this is why you get undefined  ...

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how the change you've described could cause this problem, it looks to me like that template would not have worked with either the old or the new router code.

The variables in a template come from what are known *locals*. One way to provide locals is to pass them in when calling `render`:

```
res.render("blogs/new", {
    blog: req.body.blog
});
```

You can also assign locals using `res.locals` or `app.locals`. It wouldn't be appropriate to use `app.locals` here as they would be shared between all requests but using `res.locals` would be a viable option:

```
res.locals.blog = req.body.blog;
```

The locals are merged by Express before calling the template, with the locals passed to `render` taking precedence over those on `res`.

If the old router code did work with that template then my best guess would be that some code you haven't provided was setting the relevant value on `res.locals` and your change has somehow broken that.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is specific to body-parser; require the package and set `extended` to `true` in your code :

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
```